# Limit belongs to the sum!

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

I have this question which i'm trying since a month but didn't worked out for me.
For $$a \in R, a\ne-1$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1^a+2^a+3^a+\cdot\cdot\cdot+n^a}{\mathrm{(n+1)}^{a-1}[(na+1)+(na+2)+(na+3)+\cdot\cdot\cdot+(na+n)]}=\frac{1}{60}.$$
Then a=?
I tried series formula for denominator but i couldn't make out with the numerator.I don't know how to simplify the numerator.
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1^a+2^a+3^a+\cdot\cdot\cdot+n^a}{\mathrm{(n+1)}^{a-1}[(na+1)+(na+2)+(na+3)+\cdot\cdot\cdot+(na+n)]}$$$$=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{1}^n x^a}{\mathrm{(n+1)}^{a-1}[ n^2a+n\sum_{1}^nx]}$$$$=\frac{1}{60}.$$How can i simplify the numerator?

Comment: Dunno if it is simpler, but $\sum_{x=1}^n x^a$ is a harmonic number $H_n(-a)$.

Comment: your denominator can be modified: $(na+1)+\cdots+(na+n)=n^2a+\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$

Answer (score 2):

A hint about the numerator: If each term is divided by $(n+1)^a$ the numerator over that becomes a Riemann sum for the integral of $x^a$ for $x \in [0,1].$ [There's a missing term but that doesn't matter.] So that part of the expression approaches $1/(a+1)$ as $n \to \infty.$ Maybe in combination with the rest you have found, this can give a closed form which then can be set to $1/60$ to solve for $a.$

Added note: one also has to pull out a factor of $1/n$ for the width of the rectangles, which is incorporated into the Riemann sum part. That will make a difference in how the remaining section looks before taking its limit for $n \to \infty.$ [If it's convenient, one could use a factor of $1/(n+1)$ for this, since $(1/n)/(1/(n+1) \to 1.$]